# MAX485 module, pull ups for RX and TX

Tags: rs485, pullup

I recently bought the below RS485 module. I see from the schematic they use pull-ups on pins 1 and 4 (TX and RX), can someone explain why are those pull-up resistors needed (R1 and R4)?

Secondly, pins 2 and 3 should be shorted together, and pulled high or low, depending if you want to receive or transmit data, why would they tie it to Vcc through a pull-up resistor?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Those resistors are there on RX & TX so that you have a known idle state. TTL UARTs idle high and are driven low. When the receiver is disabled, the RO pin is high impedance (basically disconnected) so the resistor would take over and pull it high to idle. If your input to DI is broken (wire disconnects) then the bus goes idle and the output idles.

In the configuration you're showing here, the pull-up on pin 2 means that the RO output is high impedance (disabled). The pull up on pin 3 means that the chip is defaulted in the transmit state. Personally, I would prefer pulling it down that way this module is not in the transmit state by default. Then your Arduino or whatever would pull the DE pin high to go into transmit state.

Yes, you can connect RE and DE together if you want, and drive high for TX and low for RX.

Answer (score 3):

It has pull-ups, because a CMOS input pin must be never left floating. Since users of such modules don't necessarily know or care about that, it is best for a module to provide pull-ups for the users so they won't complain that the module does not work or gets damaged due to user not providing pull-ups.

These pull-ups provide defaults when nothing else is driving the pins high or low. In this case, driver output is enabled, transmit data input is pulled to logic high, receiver is disabled and received data is defaulted via pull-up to high.

Secondly, pins 2 and 3 are not necessarily supposed to be shorted together in all cases, as other people may want to use the module differently to how you want to use it.

So having them separate allows the user to select if you want to transmit data, receive data, neither, or both (depends on chip - not sure if it applies to MAX485).

For example your UART might be shared with a second port for programming, so you don't want to enable receiver output as there might be another output driving the RO wire.

Comment: One use for separate RXEN and TXEN is that some systems want to listen to their own transmission (so see it's not clashing with another transmission, for example to implement a variety of collision detection).

Comment: @jonathanjo I think that may not work, as equally strong drivers, especially with wire resistance between them, won't see that the other driver is driving into another direction, as each chip monitors only it's own IO pins. However, it may be more useful to just think use cases for tri-stating the Receive Data Output.

Comment: I don't disagree with you about the drivers: but I've seen it implemented in software ... I'm now thinking about what errors it would actually detect.  Shorts, surely.  As for tristating the RXD output ... I'm working on a system right now where the CPU shares RXD with MOSI, used during in-circuit programming, and so it requires the driver's RXD to be tristate during reset.

Comment: Oh and of course power: some RS485 drivers describe DE=lo /RE=hi as shutdown.  The last datasheet I looked at had Ishutdown = 0.002 uA typ.

Comment: @jonathanjo Yes some devices have a shutdown/sleep mode but not this MAX485. There may be limited problems detected by monitoring your own transmission. A short between data wires would make the receiver output high or low permanently. More often, receivers understand short between data wires as logic high due to built-in biasing or thresholds. I think MAX485 has no biasing but hysteresis, so if you short the bus during logic 0, it may get stuck at logic 0.